# How to justify $f(n) = O(g(n))$

Tags: asymptotics, proof-techniques

The following question is in my homework:

> Is the statement $f(n) = O(g(n))$ true, when $f(n) = n/2 + 4$ and $g(n) = \sqrt{n} + 2\log_2 n + 3$?

I understand how $f(n)$ is the upper bound of $g(n)$. However, I am unsure how to prove it mathematically.

Comment: When all else fails, use the definitions.

Comment: What is *big O*?

Comment: See https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/827/683.